# Resizing a uniform.js div.selector element

Tags: jquery, css, html, media-queries

Good afternoon,
I've got a  tag that needs CSS styling, so I opted to use a jQuery plugin called Uniform.js to create an overlay div that I can style, while still allowing the user to interact with the respective  element.

If the  content for a  element is too long to display well in the layout, I've added the following to the CSS, 'text-overflow: ellipsis; text-wrap: nowrap;' to the div.selector element.

This works fine past a screen width of 444px, but it breaks horribly if you try to resize the browser window to anything smaller.

Example: [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ticaju/6/)

I know the issue lies somewhere with this div.selector element, but I can't pinpoint what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.selector span{white-space: normal;}
```

Apply this style for particular "@media" width where you want.